# How do I do a callback of the result of this objective-c function?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, callback

First of all, I'm fairly new to programming, so bear with me.. though I'm certain I learn quickly from examples.

I have the following code as part of my project:

```
-
```

-
any help is greatly appreciated, I've already wasted hours on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new block parameter to `searchPointer:`and call this block with an address you found.